# Adding a function in a returned block in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am just starting out with React and I am loving it! I bumbed into the following problem today, I want to add a onClick to a block but it wont let me. React says it cant read the property of openAbout, while its right there in the scope. So I guess I am doing something wrong, but I dont know how to look for it online :( Any help is very welcome!

Greetings,

Bram

```
    setHeads(arr) {
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach(function (item, i) {
        result.push(
            <a key={i} className="profile">
                <div className="picture" style={item.image}></div>
                <div className="name" onClick = {this.openAbout(item.name)}>{item.nickName}</div>
            </a>);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to `bind` your callback function.

Comment: This, combined with the awnser of Igor makes the function accessible, but it doesnt output the this.name, for which I requested :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setHeads(arr) {
   return arr.map((item, i) => <a key={i} className="profile">
                <div className="picture" style={item.image}></div>
                <div className="name" onClick = {e=>this.openAbout(item.name)}>{item.nickName}</div>
            </a>);
}
```

in code

```
{this.setHeads(your array)}
```

Comment: This works, but the function gets fired on init? And the onClick doesnt do anything.

Comment: i have update check now  className="name" onClick = {e=>this.openAbout(item.name)}

Comment: Great! That works :D Could you explain further? Why the "e"?

Comment: In typescript a function can create like e => { }

Comment: Ah, so I need to tell React that its passing a function? Why do I need to do it here? And not on a static element which has on onClick?

Comment: we need bind function or pass fn , alternave we can onClick = {this.openAbout.bind(this, item.name)}

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The react documentation explains pretty well why: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html